# How to flatten a nested loop in CUDA with variable length inner loop?

Tags: c++, loops, cuda, gpu

I have the following C++ code and I have to parallelise in CUDA.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int length = 4;
    const int x = 3; 
    int a[length + 1] = {0, 3, 5, 9, 12};
    int b[length * x];

    for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
        for (int j = a[i]; j < a[i+1]; j++) {
            b[i * x + j - a[i]] = a[i] + j;
        }
    }
}
```

If the inner loop was running a fixed number of times then this would have been straightforward. But since the inner loop is variable length and depends on the values obtained from the outer loop, I am not sure how this can be flatten in a way to use threads effectively.

This is just a simple example. I want the code to be able to work for very large arrays.

Edit: There are two issues that I have here. Other than the variable length loop, I am not sure how to handle - different iterations of the outer loop writing to the same `b` elements. Atomics wont be efficient for large array. Maybe changing the order in which a thread accesses adjacent elements would help?

Comment: `int length = 4; int x = 3;` -> `const int length = 4; const int x = 3;` to avoid unecessary discusison about compiler extensions. Your code as written is not standard c++

Comment: different iterations of the outer loop write to the same `b` elements, hence I dont see how you would run the outer loop in parallel

Comment: You are right. There are two separate issues that I have here. Other than the variable length loop, I am also not sure how to handle this race condition. I am thinking `atomic` but they wont be efficient for large array. Maybe changing the order in which a thread accesses adjacent elements would help but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: they are not actually seperate. The answer you got addresses both. Though, in general I would worry about shared data first, once you have chunks of work that threads can work on independently you can still see how to distribute it more effficiently

Comment: Yes. By separate I mean I also have some code, where I only have the first problem and not second. This one has both. Would the solution work if I want to tackle this issue separately or would there be a better way to deal with that.

Comment: Code that only has the variable length problem is probably algorithmically related to a sparse matrix-vector product (SpMV) using the CSR format for the matrix which is a well researched problem. There is no trivial solution to this. One can use a block or warp for each row `i` and parallelize the reduction over `j` locally but even then one can have work imbalance problems especially if some rows are much less sparse than others. [moderngpu](https://github.com/moderngpu/moderngpu) is a library that has some tools for load-balancing such irregular problems.

Comment: @paleonix Thanks a lot. I will look further into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have each thread compute 1 element of b by scanning all elements of `a`.

```
 int threadId=mapping of threads for elements of b;          
 int indexB = threadId; 
 for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
 {
    if(A[i+1] > myRangeOfB && A[i] <= myRangeOfB)
    {
       B[indexB] = A[i] + i;
    }
 }
```

This is O(N * numThreads) so its expensive but gets help from caching of `A` and if its small enough, it will be fast because all threads are doing same amount of work (depending on taken branch that is not diverging).

To further optimize this 1-dimension collision detection algorithm, you could prepare histogram or something like that for the inputs. Then just use histogram id values to put them into their targets.

It's essentially this:

```
for all elements of b
    if current element is between a(i) and a(i+k)
         set value
```

so if you access a(i) and a(i+k) uniformly, its ok.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I forgot to mention that this is just a simple example. I want the code to be able to be efficient  on very large arrays.

Comment: Then it's becoming a 1D collision detection algorithm where you check elements against fixed numbers. The code above is brute force and easy to parallelize. You could get it close to O(numberOfElements) if the collisions are uniform.

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful. Would there be a better solution to handle the variable length loop when there is no race condition of writing to the same index of `b` like in this case?

Comment: If a lot of elements of B are untouched, you can compress the work area of threads, like all threads are always writing to their element and rest of elements are not computed. Some kind of sorting and maybe extra level of indirection could help. This would take two passes instead of one.

Comment: Two passes make perfect sense. Thank you. Could you please elaborate on why sorting is needed? In my case, the elements of `a` will always be sorted so that part can be assumed.

Comment: When you sort them to "empty" vs "filled", the work can be fully equal in terms of memory operations. Nearly always all 32 threads of each warp fills an element of b.